# Getting #REF when another macro edits and sorts target worksheet

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a workbook with a few worksheets that hold recipes for various menu section in my restaurant. I have one page that I use as an 'Ingredients' data page and one that I use for making new recipes by pulling data from the 'Ingredients' sheet.

Problem is when ever I add an ingredient to the 'Ingredients' page and re-sort alphabetically (as I know this works best for vlookup) the vlookup formula replaces the table array reference in the formula with #REF e.g

```
=VLOOKUP(A10,Ingredients!A2:H320,5,TRUE)
```

gets changed to

```
=VLOOKUP(A11,#REF!A2:H320,5,TRUE)
```

is there away for making 'Ingredients' static and none change-able? Does "$" work for table names as well as cell references?

ANy help would be great and I will answer any questions that help.

Matt

Comment: 1) `as I know this works best for vlookup` - you could change last parameter of vlookup TRUE->FALSE. In that case *there is no need to sort data*, i.e. `=VLOOKUP(A10,Ingredients!A2:H320,5,FALSE)` work with unsorted data. 2) If you still want to sort data, try to use `=VLOOKUP(A10,Ingredients!A:H,5,FALSE)`

Comment: It is easier for it to be sorted alphabetically as I am using a drop-box for selecting the ingredients and its easier to find the ingredients that way. If there is no way of stopping excel messing with the formula then I will go with unsorted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(A10,INDIRECT("Ingredients!A2:H320"),5,TRUE)
```